# terminology: accumulation points, limit point, cluster point

Tags: general-topology, terminology

In a topological space $X$, what would be the most common terms to describe the following two properties about a point $x\in X$ and a subset $S\subseteq X$.

I) For every open set $U$ with $x\in U$, $U\cap S\ne \emptyset$.

II) For every open set $U$ with $x\in U$, $U\cap (S-\{x\})\ne \emptyset$.

Is there some consensus or are there different camps? if the latter, are there preferences for one over the other among practitioners of certain disciplines?

Comment: I would say that *limit point* is the most common term for (II), though *accumulation point* is also used. I reserve *cluster point* for a cluster point of a net, which need not be a limit point of the range of the net; *accumulation point* is also used for this. I would not use any of the three terms for (I): in that case $x$ is simply in the closure of $S$.

Comment: My pleasure. $\;$